# Custom delegate method not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, delegates

I'm trying to adapt Apple's example of TableViewUpdates (expanding TableView Cells) to my own application, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I tried narrowing the problem down and I think I know where the problem lies now.

Apple uses a UITableViewController as the base controller for the view, but I have a UIViewController that has the UITableViewDelegate and DataSource as delegate methods. I added the HeaderViewDelegate to it like this:

```
@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, IngredientHeaderViewDelegate>
```

IngredientHeaderFooterView.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol IngredientHeaderViewDelegate;

@interface IngredientHeaderFooterView : UITableViewHeaderFooterView

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTitle;

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet id <IngredientHeaderViewDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger section;

- (void)toggleOpenWithUserAction:(BOOL)userAction;

@end

@protocol IngredientHeaderViewDelegate <NSObject>

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger hoi;

@optional
- (void)sectionHeaderView:(IngredientHeaderFooterView *)sectionHeaderView sectionOpened:(NSInteger)section;
- (void)sectionHeaderView:(IngredientHeaderFooterView *)sectionHeaderView sectionClosed:(NSInteger)section;

@end
```

In IngredientHeaderFooterView.m:

```
- (void)toggleOpenWithUserAction:(BOOL)userAction {

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(sectionHeaderView:sectionOpened:)]) {
        NSLog(@"Test1");
        [self.delegate sectionHeaderView:self sectionOpened:self.section];
    }
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(sectionHeaderView:sectionClosed:)]) {
        NSLog(@"Test2");
        [self.delegate sectionHeaderView:self sectionClosed:self.section];
    }
}
```

And in my UIViewController that implements the delegate:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

IngredientHeaderFooterView *ingredientHeaderView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];

IngredientDescriptionInfo *ingredientInfo = (self.sectionInfoArray)[section];
ingredientInfo.headerView = ingredientHeaderView;

ingredientHeaderView.lblTitle.text = ingredientInfo.play.name;
ingredientHeaderView.section = section;
ingredientHeaderView.delegate = self;

return ingredientHeaderView;
}
```

But respondsToSelector: always returns false. What could it be?

Comment: And does your view controller implement those two methods? It's not enough to just assign delegates...

Comment: Yes, offcourse. I put a breakpoint and NSLog on top but it doesn't even go past that. So that's why I think it's not getting called.

Answer (score 2):

In your `SearchViewController`, you need to implement both methods from the protocol `IngredientHeaderViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)sectionHeaderView:(IngredientHeaderFooterView *)sectionHeaderView sectionOpened:(NSInteger)section
{
  NSLog(@"section opened");
}

 - (void)sectionHeaderView:(IngredientHeaderFooterView *)sectionHeaderView sectionClosed:(NSInteger)section
{
  NSLog(@"section closed");
}
```

Also, don't forget to actually assign the delegate in `IngredientHeaderFooterView`. Make sure that it's not `nil` when `toggleOpenWithUserAction:` is called.

If you make sure that the methods are implemented and the `delegate` is actually assigned you should be good :)

Comment: I had implemented both methods (they also go the declaration when i cmd+click it), but what do you mean by assigning the delegate?

Comment: are you sure the delegate is not nil? what happens if you put a break point in `toggleOpenWithUserAction:` and type in the debugger console: `po self.delegate`, does it return `nil` or is there an object assigned to it?

Comment: it is `nil`. you say that i need to assign it in `IngredientHeaderFooterView` but Apple doesn't do that in it's example?

Comment: ok, at least we have identified your issue :) I will update my answer with a recommendation how you can make sure your delegate is assigned :)

Comment: hmm, actually I think it's a bit strange that `delegate` is nil, since you are actually assigning it after having created it with `ingredientHeaderView.delegate = self;`

Comment: so I cant give a straight recommendation after all, seems like you'd have to dive a bit deeper and debug to what happens after this line and check whether the delegate is actually assigned. difficult to tell from here what the _exact_ issue is.

Comment: can you send me the project somehow? i'll take a look then.

Comment: thanks for all your trouble :) but I've decided to copy the example code from Apple ones more, but this time without changing the variable names. got it to work, so I guess it was due to the refactoring of me that did go wrong. going to change them one by one now :)